# Reading multiple RDS files

Tags: r

I have a directory with multiple RDS files (300+) that I would like to read and combine, these RDS files share the same basic format but have different number of rows & a few different columns in each file. I have the simple code to read one RDS file (All files have same "Events-3digitnumber-4digitnumber-6digitnumber.RDS")

```
    mydata <- readRDS("Events-104-2014-752043.RDS")
```

Being new to data science I'm sure this simple answer that I'm missing but would I have to use something like list.files() and either lapply or some for loop.

Answer (score 17):

Just to add a `tidyverse` answer:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- list.files(pattern = ".RDS") %>%
  map(readRDS) %>% 
  bind_rows()
```

**Update:**

It is advised to use `map_dfr` for binding rows and `map_dfc` for binding columns, much more efficient:

```
df <- list.files(pattern = ".RDS") %>%
  map_dfr(readRDS)
```

Answer (score 4):

First a reproducible example:

```
data(iris)
# make sure that the two data sets (iris, iris2) have different columns
iris2 = copy(iris)
iris2$Species2 = iris2$Species
iris2$Species = NULL

saveRDS(iris, "Events-104-2014-752043.RDS")
saveRDS(iris2, "Events-104-2015-782043.RDS")
```

Now you need to

1. find all file names
2. read the data
3. combine the data to one table (if you want that)

I would use `data.table::rbindlist` because it handles differing columns for you when you set `fill = TRUE`:

```
require(data.table)
files = list.files(path = '.', pattern = '^Events-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{6}\\.RDS$')
dat_list = lapply(files, function (x) data.table(readRDS(x)))
dat = rbindlist(dat_list, fill = TRUE)
```

Comment: Running the code above worked great! Managed to combine all my files from that directory

Answer (score 4):

Because the solution from [FMM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51937327/9978136) did not work for me with huge data sets, I replaced `bind_rows()` with `data.table::rbindlist()`:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

df <- list.files(pattern = ".rds") %>%
      map(readRDS) %>% 
      data.table::rbindlist()
```

Answer (score 1):

complementing FMM's answer above,
you may need to include the "full.names=TRUE" in the list.files command to allow map_dfr to read it properly, depending on the path to your files.

```
df <- list.files(pattern = ".RDS", full.names=T)%>%
 map_dfr(readRDS)
```